# Why the D3.js event.transform.rescaleY(yScale) function works differently on wheel and mouse zoom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I have a simple plot with the zoom functionality along Y axis.
When I use wheel to change the zoom it works OK.
But when I use mouse to drag then at the beginning the chart jumps.

Here is the function I use on the zoom event:
I guess there should be added some test if the event is wheel or mouse and some more calculations in case of the mouse event.

```
function zoom(event: any) {
 console.log(event);
 let new_yScale = event.transform.rescaleY(yScale);

 console.log(new_yScale);
 console.log(new_yScale.domain());
 console.log(new_yScale.range());
 setMinY(new_yScale.domain()[0]);
 setMaxY(new_yScale.domain()[1]);
}
```

[image: Gif representing the jumping]

I am using D3.js and React.

[Code sandbox link:](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-stallman-15jmky?file=/src/Chart.tsx)

[Application demo:](https://15jmky.csb.app/)

In the attachment is the gif showing the strange behaviour.

I tried to console.log the event.transform result and noticed the event.transform values are different on wheel event and mouseevent. But I do not know how to recalculate the mouseevent result to be compatible with the wheel.

Comment: I already noticed that the jump value is equal to the top margin of the container element. When the margin of the container is 0 and body margin is also 0 then this jump does not appears. But reducing margin to 0 is not a solution because this is a component so we cannot predict how it will be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it here:
https://p89vne.csb.app/

I found this tutorial very useful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxUyI2wfYSI&list=PLDZ4p-ENjbiPo4WH7KdHjh_EMI7Ic8b2B&index=18

I think the initial example had flaw design ( with recreating the svg every tick) and that was the main problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).